# Are blue eggs lower in cholesterol than other eggs?

Tags: nutrition, cholesterol, egg

I just bought some eggs from a local farmer in the same office building. She told me *blue eggs* were lower in cholesterol than other eggs so I bought them. The difference in price was 50¢, so it didn't matter much. Is there any merit to this claim?

[image]

Comment: Cholesterol is not bad anyway.

Answer (score 8):

**No.** At least this is what the [Ameraucana Breeders Club](http://www.ameraucana.org/faq.html) has to say on this issue:

> **Are blue eggs, from Ameraucanas and Araucanas, lower in cholesterol than white and brown eggs?**
>
> This is a very common question because years ago some hatcheries claimed that these eggs were reported to be lower in cholesterol and higher in nutritional value than other chicken eggs. William O. Cawley, Extension Poultry Specialist at Texas A&M University, wrote a paper, POULTRYDOM'S MYSTERY CHICKEN - THE ARAUCANA, 10/79, that sets the record straight.